# Symfony 2.8: Percent form field validation incorrect for fractions

Tags: forms, symfony, validation

When I try to save a Symfony 2.8 form field of type "percent" with a fractional value, the validation returns

> This value should not be null.

I have set up the field in my entity as per instructions:

```
/**
 * @var decimal
 *
 * @ORM\Column(
          name="total_percent", 
          type="decimal", 
          precision=14, 
          scale=8, 
          nullable=false
   )
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
private $percent;
```

and I create my field as such:

```
->add('percent', 
      PercentType::class, 
      array(
          'scale' => 8, 
          'attr' => array('class' => 'percent_field'))
      )
```

I have double checked the database and I can create entries with fractions, so the issue seems to be with Symfony's forms. However, I cannot find the issue in my code.
Has anyone successfully implemented this. In essence I want to be able to save a percent like 1.5%.
Any constructive ideas (pertaining to the issue at hand) are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column):

> **precision**: The precision for a decimal (exact numeric) column (applies
>   only for decimal column), which is the maximum number of digits that
>   are stored for the values.
>
> **scale**: The scale for a decimal (exact numeric) column (applies only
>   for decimal column), which represents the number of digits to the
>   right of the decimal point and must not be greater than precision.

to store a simple percentage value like `1.5`% and a relative (positive) range from `0.0` to `100.0` you should modify the column mapping:

```
/**
 * @var decimal
 *
 * @ORM\Column(
 *     name="total_percent", 
 *     type="decimal", 
 *     precision=4, # <-- THIS IS NEEDED TO BE ALLOWED TO STORE ALSO 100.0,
 *     scale=1, # <-- THIS ALLOWS ONLY 1 DECIMAL
 *     nullable=false
 *  )
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 * @Assert\Range(
 *      min = 0,
 *      max = 100,
 *      minMessage = "Min % is 0",
 *      maxMessage = "Max % is 100"
 * )
 */
private $percent;
```

and the form field:

```
->add('percent', 
      PercentType::class, 
      array(
          'type' => 'integer', # <-- SET THE TYPE AS INTEGER!
          'scale' => 1,
          'attr' => array('class' => 'percent_field')
     )
 )
```

To avoid values upper then `100.0` use the `Range` constraint like in my example.

In my tests this configuration works pretty well, allowing decimal separed by commas like "`34,2`" or "`1,5`" and all the values like "`23,5543`" will be rounded to the closest value in defect or excess (in this case will be "`23,6`").

Comment: @roland I'm not sure if the validation error comes due to the wrong settings but your mapping was surely wrong. If the error not disappear take a look at the Symfony profiler -> form to see the data passed to the form. Let me know :-)

Comment: Symfony translates a "percent" field value into its actual number, e.g. 1.5% is stored as 0.015 in the database (this does work, I can manually add that value to the database). So in your case, I would not be able to store 1.5 (precision=3, scale=1). As it would be stored as 0.015. With scale=1 this would make it 0.0 which will trigger a not null error?

Comment: @roland I updated my answer with a full working configuration. PS: remember to insert the value using a **comma** "," and not a dot (Symfony will take care to transform the "view" value before store it in DB).

Comment: @roland In my answer I've not used the `fractional` type to follow your example (1,5%) but if you have a specific use case I need to know the range of the values you need to store to give you a better and specific answer.

Comment: I have updated my code to mimic yours (except for: precision=5 and scale=2). Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.
Submitting 1.5 results in: "This value is not valid."
Submitting 1,5 results in: "Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given" (maybe this has to do with localization of sorts.

Comment: Investigating further, I see that the value "1.5" is translated to _null_: http://ctrlv.in/948990
This with the error bubbling: http://ctrlv.in/948991